# MySQL Cluster is a NoSQL technology?

Tags: mysql, nosql

MySQL Cluster is a NoSQL technology? Or is another way to use the relational database?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Cluster uses MySQL Servers as API nodes to provide SQL access/a relational view to the data. The data itself is stored in the data nodes - which are separate processes. The fastest way to access the data is through the C++ API (NDB API) - in fact that is how the MySQL Server gets to the data.

There are a number of NoSQL access methods for getting to the data (that avoid going through the MySQL Server/releational view) including Rest, Java, JPA, LDAP and most recently the [Memcached key-value store API](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/scalabale-persistent-ha-nosql-memcache-storage-using-mysql-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

It is another way to use the database by spreading it across multiple machines and allowing a simplified concurrent-master setup. It comes with a bit of a cost in that your indexes cannot exceed the amount of RAM available to hold them. To you application, it looks no different than regular MySQL.

Perhaps take a look at [Can MySQL Cluster handle a terabyte database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850307/can-mysql-cluster-handle-a-terabyte-database/850351#850351).